# How to redirect users to login to service?

Tags: android, api, retrofit2, pinterest, mobile-development

I'm in the process of creating an app in Android Studio that is integrated with the Pinterest API. Like other services, Pinterest requires users to log into their accounts by redirecting them to their site with certain parameters (response type, scope, client_id, etc).
This is what they have as an example for the request to direct users to:

```
https://api.pinterest.com/oauth/?
    response_type=code&
    redirect_uri=https://mywebsite.com/connect/pinterest/&
    client_id=12345&
    scope=read_public,write_public&
    state=768uyFys
```

How do I use this to direct users to the Pinterest login page? Is this a GET or POST request I would need to use Retrofit for?

Link to Pinterest API documentation: https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api

Thank you in advance,

Hannah

Answer (score 0):

Pinterest have an Android SDK here: https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/sdks/android/ under the Authentication, they have created a sample login using the SDK

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late response. I looked through that before but that's an example in using its PDKClient, which has been deprecated for a while. I'm wondering if there's a way to do with normal API endpoints.